# Does the scene in Tin Star S01 E05 with a pool table contain a mistake?

Tags: plot-explanation, tin-star

In this episode there is a scene where Whitey (Oliver Coppersmith), is playing pool whilst keeping tabs on the Police Chief (Tim Roth). We see him take a shot, but clearly see there are 2 cue balls (white balls) on the table.

**Is this just an oversight, a pretty poor one to be honest, or in parts of Canada / North America, is there a type of pool game that requires 2 cue balls?**

Apologies for lack of supporting image.

I watched the scene a couple of times, this is not my mistake, 2 white balls are clearly on the table.

Pictures posted in accepted answer below would suggest I did make a mistake!

Comment: Is it definitely pool? Could it be a [Billiard Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_billiards)?

Comment: @Paulie_D looks like a regular pool table to me, although you don't see the whole table, he's playing a shot into one of the middle pockets. The other balls looked like they were stripes/solids.

Comment: *"this is not my mistake"* Apologies in advance, but I have to double check: No chance the colors were a bit off and it was the *yellow* ball? They're sometimes easy to confuse even in real life, under those lights.

Comment: @Walt I suppose that's a possibility.... Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Haven't seen it, mfraid.

Comment: I only have access to E1 so far.

Comment: What other colors of balls do you see? I believe snooker uses multiple white and red balls.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Er, there's only one white ball in snooker, AFAIK.

Comment: Depending on the camera point of view, a striped ball can look like a white one if the white portion if directly facing you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As the OP commented

> Not that scene, it is just after one of his colleagues (male) has confronted him at the bar. ..

I checked the `Episode 5` and found the scene you talking about,

[image]

Here we can see that he is hitting a ball with cue ball and another ball looks like cue ball is in the scene.

Before that scene when Tim Roth's police friend coming into the the bar scene, we get a look at the pool board.

[image]

In the both images rather than cue ball, all other balls are in similiar places, and in second image we can see the yellow shade on the second ball and its now clear that only the white part of a striped ball was visible in the first image.

Comment: *"no holes"* Er, that's the problem. OP's sure it was a pool table and saw the character *taking a shot into the middle pocket* (see comments under Q).

Comment: For the setting of the show, near Calgary i think, small town.... new oil refinery built, lots of workers frequenting the bar, billiards doesn't seem like a good fit. And yes, pockets were in the table, I would think it was safe to assume it was a pool table.

Comment: updated my answer, is that the scene you are talking about?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers who find this question and its answer months or years from now, it would probably be better to remove the "old answer" entirely, instead of just striking it out.

Comment: @steve ok removed my older answer entirely, thanks for noticing

Comment: @irshadjm Not that scene, it is just after one of his colleagues (male) has confronted him at the bar. The colleague leaves and you see Whitey take a shot, and 2 cue balls appear to be present. Maybe check E05, will update my question If i have made a mistake on the episode.

Comment: Though this pic at least brings another possibility to mind: that only the white part of a striped ball was visible.

Comment: @NealS I found the scene, its from E5 not E4, and the second cue ball you said was yellow striped white ball and only one side of that is shown in that scene